# Jackson configuration to write enum as object

Tags: serialization, enums, deserialization, jackson

When I try to serialize and deserialize a `Set<ClassA<?>>` of generic objects that look as follows:

```
public class ClassA<T> {

private ClassB datum;
private T value;
...
}
```

If that `T` happens to be an enum, it gets written as a String value. This is fine for serialization, but when I deserialize, it's not possible to know if the String value is an enum or not. Jackson then turns the resulting object into a String and you get a `ClassA<String>` instead of `ClassA<SomeEnumType>`.

Is there a configuration in Jackson to have it create some hints that the value is an enum? Or perhaps turn the enum into a JSON object rather then a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a configuration in Jackson to have it create some hints that the value is an enum?

It's possible to deserialize to an enum instance from a matching JSON string value.  Or is this somehow not applicable to your situation?

Here is an example.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String myEnumJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(MyEnum.MyEnum1);

    System.out.println(myEnumJson);

    MyEnum myEnum = mapper.readValue(myEnumJson, MyEnum.class);

    System.out.println(myEnum);

    Set<ClassA<MyEnum>> set = new TreeSet<ClassA<MyEnum>>();
    set.add(new ClassA<MyEnum>(new ClassB("bValue7"), MyEnum.MyEnum1));
    set.add(new ClassA<MyEnum>(new ClassB("bValue8"), MyEnum.MyEnum2));
    String setJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(set);
    System.out.println(setJson);

    TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();

    Set<ClassA<MyEnum>> setCopy = mapper.readValue(setJson,
        typeFactory.constructCollectionType(Set.class,
            typeFactory.constructParametricType(ClassA.class, MyEnum.class)));
    System.out.println(setCopy);
  }
}

class ClassA<T> implements Comparable<ClassA<T>>
{
  ClassB datum;
  T value;

  ClassA()
  {
  }

  ClassA(ClassB datum, T value)
  {
    this.datum = datum;
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ClassA<T> o)
  {
    return 42;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("ClassA: datum=%s, value=%s", datum, value);
  }
}

class ClassB
{
  String bValue;

  ClassB()
  {
  }

  ClassB(String bValue)
  {
    this.bValue = bValue;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("ClassB: bValue=%s", bValue);
  }
}

enum MyEnum
{
  MyEnum1("myEnum1", 1), MyEnum2("myEnum2", 2);

  String name;
  int id;

  MyEnum(String name, int id)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
"MyEnum1"
MyEnum1
[{"datum":{"bValue":"bValue7"},"value":"MyEnum1"},{"datum":{"bValue":"bValue8"},"value":"MyEnum2"}]
[ClassA: datum=ClassB: bValue=bValue7, value=MyEnum1, ClassA: datum=ClassB: bValue=bValue8, value=MyEnum2]
```

If for some reason it's necessary to have enums serialized as POJOs, then it appears custom serialization processing is required.  [Serializing enums with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766791/serializing-enums-with-jackson)

Comment: For the interested, I logged Jackson issue 725 to discuss and track a possible enhancement for easy configuration to (de)serialize the state of an enum. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-725 Vote and comment if you want it.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I didn't know about typeFactory.constructCollectionType and typeFactory.constructParametricType. That's what I was looking for.