# Why Json does not get generated properly for java enum?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, enums

I have a StepEnum which i want to generate json like this:

```
{"success":true,"stepList":[{"name":"My First Step","index":0,"status":"active"},{"name":"My Second Step","index":1,"status":"inactive"}]}
```

However I'm getting output like this:

```
 {"success":true,"stepList":["MY_FIRST_STEP","MY_SECOND_STEP"]}
```

What change do i need to make in my Enum class.
Json is being generated  by spring framework.
Here is my StepEnum class:

```
public enum StepEnum {
    MY_FIRST_STEP("My First Step",0),
    MY_SECOND_STEP("My Second Step",1);

    private String label;
    private int index;
    private String status;
    private StepEnum(String label, int index) {
        this.label = label;this.index = index;
    }
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing enums with Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766791/serializing-enums-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue, and answer, is addressed in this article:
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

As an aside, I find having setters for an enum property to be highly suspect.  Enums are static, shared, etc... and to my thinking it takes a very unusual situation for them to not be immutable.

Comment: @BrainT It's a practice that happens more and more, since Enums are now actively used to implement the `Singleton` pattern. That also goes for single instance stateful handlers (which may be the case here).

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered that.  Still, to help team members do things well, I would consider these setters the exception and not the rule.  Special javadoc would not be amiss.