# How can I add an array into JSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have this code:

```
public enum Make{
  FORD, BMW, AUDI
}

@Entity
public class User{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  
  private String email;
 
  ...
  @OneToMany(...)
  private Set<Cars> favoriteMakes = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I would like to be able to update a user by sending json with a list of favorite makes.
F.e.:
New user:

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "email" : "email@mail.com",
    ...
   "favoriteMakes" : []
}
```

I want to achieve :

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "email" : "email@mail.com",
    ...
   "favoriteMakes" : ["FORD", "AUDI"]
}
```

The things I've tried:

```
"favoriteMakes" : ["FORD", "AUDI"],
"favoriteMakes" : ["0", "2"],
"favoriteMakes" : [0, 2],
```

Comment: why serializing/ deserializing  the User object is not enough?

Comment: Hi, @Inga890, I am pretty new to this, so can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I created a short example just to show how to serialize and deserialize Json using newtonsoft

```
    public enum Make
    {
        FORD, BMW, AUDI
    }
    public partial class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("favoriteMakes")]
        public Make[] FavoriteMakes { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            var myUser = new User();
            myUser.FavoriteMakes = new Make[1];
            myUser.FavoriteMakes[0] = Make.AUDI;
            var sz = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myUser);
            User dsz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(sz);
        }

        

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to add, that this is Java. The thing is that I want to do it with a put request, as I am creating a REST API

Comment: how about this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871013/java-convert-object-consisting-enum-to-json-object