# How to custom serialize & deserialize enums using FasterXML?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using Spring Web MVC with FasterXML.

I have a bean with enum field and I'd like this field to be serialized like this:

```
{
  id: 0,
  name: "VALUE0",
  title: "First Value"
}
```

I've created an interface `TitledEnum` with `getTitle()` method, so my enum field implements this interface. So I have all the required data: id & name from `Enum`, and title from `TitledEnum.getTitle()`;

So the question is: how to configure serialize / deserialize?

====
UPDATE: Samples:

```
public enum MyEnum implements TitledEnum {
  VALUE0 ("My First Value");
  //implementation here
}

public class MyBean {
  //@JsonSerialize or @JsonDeserialize here if needed
  private MyEnum enumField;
}
```

=====
Update. 
I'm looking for a general solution, one serializer for all enums

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I want to find a general solution

Comment: It's really a duplicate. Thanks, @VladimirVagaytsev. The answer was under that question, but not choosen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23998866/1728511