# Spring Boot Controller - Enum parameter as Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, enums, jackson

I have a spring boot controller, one of my parameters is an Enum. The enum has a string value. I want to pass as the parameter the value of the enum and the controller to give me the Enum. Can this be done?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/")
public MyResponse getResponse ( @RequestParam(value = "version") final ProjectVersion version ) {
   ...bla bla bla...
}

public enum ProjectVersion {
    VERSION_1 ("1.00")
    VERSION_2 ("2.00")

    private final String version;

    ProjectVersion ( String version ) {
        this.version = version;
    }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
        return this.version;
     }

}
```

I want to be able to make a request as follows:

http://myhost.com/mypath?version=1.00

And get in the controller the ProjectVersion.VERSION_1

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, with custom serializer. See this, exactly yours case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766791/serializing-enums-with-jackson

Comment: If you pass `VERSION_1` it will work, if you pass the internal value it won't then you would need to create a custom converter yourself.

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible as is. You have to create your custom converter to convert from a `String` to `ProjectVersion`.

For example first defines the converter from a `String` to `ProjectVersion`:

```
public class ProjectVersionConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
    return targetType.getType().equals(ProjectVersion.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
    return Collections.singleton(new ConvertiblePair(String.class , ProjectVersion.class));
  }

  @Override
  public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
    return ProjectVersion.findByVersion((String)source);
  }
}
```

Then register it:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new ProjectVersionConverter());
  }
}
```

You can skip the registration if you define `ProjectVersionConverter` as a Spring bean. (This code has not be tested).

Comment: Using argument resolver is cleaner and better approach.

Comment: I do not agree. A converter should not bother that the value is passed as a request param or as a path variable. As long as the right annotation is used, with an agnostic converter, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to pass (for each request) the argument to the `Controller` method, the clean solution would be to use [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html), so that
**Spring container can dynamically inject your ProjectVersion argument to the Controller method** as shown below:

**`ProjectVersionArgumentResolver` class:**

```
public class ProjectVersionArgumentResolver implements 
                                    HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(ProjectVersion.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                   ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
                   NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
                   WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

        return ProjectVersion.fromString(nativeWebRequest.getParameter("version"));
    }
}
```

**Spring-boot ApplicationLauncher class:**

```
public class MyProjectApplicationLauncher extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> 
                                           argumentResolvers) {
        //add the new resolver
        argumentResolvers.add(new MyMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProjectApplicationLauncher.class, args);
    }
}
```

**`ProjectVersion` class:**

```
public enum ProjectVersion {

    //add your existing code

    //Add fromString method to convert string to enum 
    public static ProjectVersion fromString(String input) {
        for (ProjectVersion projectVersion : ProjectVersion.values()) {
          if (projectVersion.version.equals(input)) {
            return projectVersion;
          }
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Better use methodParameter.getParameterName() instead of hardcoded string "version". So ProjectVersion.fromString(nativeWebRequest.getParameter(methodParameter.getParameterName()));